# Different WebView-Results

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I need to open a website in fullscreen, in this way I use:

```
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

So far, no problems.

After calling `loadURL` I get a website, which is not in "Overview-Mode" (only part of the whole website). When I call `loadURL` again after the first call everything fits.

Why do I have to call `loadURL` two times?

The called website contains a little bit of `jQuery`, but this shouldn´t be interesting for the size?

In adition I set `webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the website you are loading has viewport meta tag and is setting its own viewport?

Comment: The Website has it´s own viewport meta tag. Why do I get two diffent results? The tag must be in both loaded websites, but it only works after the second load of the website...